# How to show dynamic dates with month name of current month and previous month in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js, momentjs

how can I get all the dates of the current and previous month in moment.js?
I was able to get the months but unable to find the dates of months
The below code if for getting months is there any similar code for getting dates also?

```
var labels = moment.monthsShort();
```

i want to show something like
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9izW.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//sample to display february days
var months = moment.monthsShort();

var datesofmonth = createAllDatesOfMonth(months[1], 2021)

console.log(datesofmonth);


function createAllDatesOfMonth(month, year) {
  let year_month = year + "-" + month;
  let nbdays = moment(year_month, "YYYY-MMM").daysInMonth();
  return Array.from(Array(nbdays).keys()).map((d) => month + " " + (d + 1));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much, sir. it really helped me.

Comment: @Divyesh glad to help you, dont forget to validate and upvote to close the question

Comment: closed question. still need some more reputation to upvote. will surely do whenever possible.